# Converting Java program into Object Oriented format (Basic)

Tags: java, oop

I am a beginner Java programmer and have toiled over this for quite some time. I need to convert the program below into OOP format and cannot get it to compile without error. I figured I would post the working non-formatted program rather than my failed and choppy attempts. If anyone could convert the below program into OOP, it would be very much appreciated. Please forgive any inefficiencies or sloppiness as I am new to this.

Thanks for helping

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Turtle3 {

  public static void drawLine(Turtle myrtle, Color color, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    myrtle.hide();
    myrtle.penUp();
    myrtle.setPenColor(color);
    myrtle.moveTo(x1, y1); 
    myrtle.penDown(); 
    myrtle.moveTo(x2, y2);  
  }

  public static void setPenWidth(int w) {
    World worldObj = new World(); 
    Turtle myrtle = new Turtle(200, 200, worldObj); 
    Turtle billy = new Turtle(100, 700, worldObj);
    Turtle thomas = new Turtle(100, 100, worldObj);
    myrtle.setColor(Color.RED);
    myrtle.setPenWidth(50);
    myrtle.forward(50);
    myrtle.show();
    billy.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    billy.setPenWidth(100);
    billy.forward(300);
    thomas.show();
    thomas.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    thomas.setPenWidth(100);
    thomas.forward(50);
    thomas.show();
  };

  public static void main(String[] args) {      
    World worldObj = new World();
    Turtle myrtleTheTurtle = new Turtle(0, 0, worldObj); 

    drawLine(myrtleTheTurtle, Color.RED, 10, 20, 700, 20);      
    drawLine(myrtleTheTurtle, Color.BLUE, 10, 40, 700, 40);
    drawLine(myrtleTheTurtle, Color.BLACK, 10, 60, 700, 60);              
    drawLine(myrtleTheTurtle, Color.BLACK, 10, 80, 700, 80);
    drawLine(myrtleTheTurtle, Color.BLACK, 10, 100, 700, 100);
    drawLine(myrtleTheTurtle, Color.RED, 10, 120, 700, 120);      
    drawLine(myrtleTheTurtle, Color.BLUE, 10, 140, 700, 140);
    drawLine(myrtleTheTurtle, Color.BLACK, 10, 160, 700, 160);              
    drawLine(myrtleTheTurtle, Color.BLACK, 10, 180, 700, 180);
    drawLine(myrtleTheTurtle, Color.BLACK, 10, 200, 700, 200);
    drawLine(myrtleTheTurtle, Color.RED, 10, 220, 700, 220);      
    drawLine(myrtleTheTurtle, Color.BLUE, 10, 240, 700, 240);
    drawLine(myrtleTheTurtle, Color.RED, 10, 260, 700, 260);      
    drawLine(myrtleTheTurtle, Color.BLUE, 10, 280, 700, 280);
    drawLine(myrtleTheTurtle, Color.BLACK, 10, 300, 700, 300);              
    drawLine(myrtleTheTurtle, Color.BLACK, 10, 320, 700, 320);
    drawLine(myrtleTheTurtle, Color.BLACK, 10, 340, 700, 340);
    drawLine(myrtleTheTurtle, Color.RED, 10, 360, 700, 360);      
    drawLine(myrtleTheTurtle, Color.BLUE, 10, 380, 700, 380);
    drawLine(myrtleTheTurtle, Color.BLACK, 10, 400, 700, 400);              
    drawLine(myrtleTheTurtle, Color.BLACK, 10, 420, 700, 420);
    drawLine(myrtleTheTurtle, Color.BLACK, 10, 440, 700, 440);
    drawLine(myrtleTheTurtle, Color.BLUE, 10, 460, 700, 460);
    drawLine(myrtleTheTurtle, Color.BLACK, 10, 480, 700, 480);
    drawLine(myrtleTheTurtle, Color.BLACK, 480, 10, 480, 700);
    drawLine(myrtleTheTurtle, Color.BLACK, 180, 10, 180, 700);
    drawLine(myrtleTheTurtle, Color.BLACK, 480, 10, 480, 700);
    drawLine(myrtleTheTurtle, Color.BLACK, 330, 10, 330, 700);

    setPenWidth(50);  
  }//end of main method
}//end of class
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking. You are already using OOP in your `setPenWidth()` method. If you want to use more OOP in your program, you would probably want to move your method `drawLine()` to the `Turtle` class and change it to something like

```
public void drawLine(Color color, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    this.hide();
    this.penUp();
    this.setPenColor(color);
    this.moveTo(x1, y1); 
    this.penDown(); 
    this.moveTo(x2, y2);  
}
```

which refers to the current instance of `Turtle` without needing to pass it as an argument. NOTE: You must take away the static keyword for this to work. Then, you have to change your code in the main method to utilize this by changing your calls to `drawLine()` from `drawLine(myrtleTheTurtle, color, x1, y1, x2, y2);` to `myrtleTheTurtle.drawLine(color, x1, y1, x2, y2)`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "want to move your method drawLine() to the Turtle class" because it is already in that class along with everything else.

Comment: cannot find symbol - method hide                                                                   This is the error I get when I run the program with your instructions

Comment: All of your stuff is in the Turtle3 class. I meant to move it to the "Turtle" class, which defines the type of the Turtles, such as Myrtle, Billy, and Thomas